# Wrong Kivy widget positions on Surface Pro4

Tags: kivy

I am relatively new in Kivy. Having studied quite a bit on my laptop, everything works fine until i started working on my surface pro 4. All my buttons were placed in wrong positions, irrespective of how I specify the position, pos or pos_hint, eg: 
[the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyyZd.jpg)

above is the window that appears when the following code is run:

```
<Button>:
    color: .8, .9, 0, 1
    font_size: 31
    size_hint: .4, .3

<FloatLayout>
    Button:
        text: 'button1'
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'top': 1}
    Button:
        text: 'button2'
        pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'y': 0}
```

could this be due to issues with OpenGL on surface pro 4 or could I have done something totally dumb?

Comment: By the way, the python code is supposed to return the FloatLayout() when the app class is run.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the documentation, I was able to locate the config.ini file on my c: drive and changed the rotation value from 90 to 0. rotation = 0 and my widgets are placed as expected. Kudos to the Kivy.org team, great documentation.